# Right Path For Custom Php Files Include Folder in Magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I need to include some custom Php files in Magento root directory. Right now i have used "Media" folder to include my custom Php files. So "Media" folder is right directory to use my custom Php Files?

Any Help Much Appreciate

Thanks.

Comment: What purpose do these files serve? Are they lib files? Relevant to a specific module? Do they need to be distributed?

Comment: Yes. i would like to include these files for my custom modules.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the purpose of the files. Are you calling them directly, do they need to be publicly accessible?

Comment: Yes. I am calling these files directly to my custom module. is this right ?

Comment: I would put them in a helper or model if they are called in your module. If it is a matter of wanting to run myurl.com/custom.php you can accomplish this with rewrites.

Answer (score 3):

Please refer this below site link for your reference:

[Click here to refer your answer](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/structure.htm)

- media (directory) - This is the storage of the Magento media files - images out of the box, generated thumbnails, uploaded products images. It is also used as a container for importing images through the mass import/export tools.
- lib (directory) - The Magento core code is located in this folder. It contains the software's PHP libraries.

I am not sure media(directory) is the right one or not. But this link is very helpful to you.